# ListFragment in android without having listview

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

This Android code for MainActivity but its not working in my case
but from where i copied it working fine there so please tell where i messed up.

I am new to Android development so please help me.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Onlinechat"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="22sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Onlinechat"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"/>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <fragment
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/fragmentlist"
                android:name="es.esy.buddy.com.simplechat.ListOfOnlineMember"
                tools:layout="@layout/listviewonlinitems" />

        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Code for Fragment list item which we where going to show in fragment at    runtime.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Listitem1"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageviewshow"
            android:src="@drawable/wallpaper6"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:text="Tuneer Mahatpure"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:id="@+id/txtName"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:id="@+id/txtNumber"
                android:text="7828743317"
                android:gravity="start|bottom"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Java Code for fragment list but i want to use listview for this purpose but i am not able to intialise listview in fragment java code i want to know is there any way to use listview in fragment java code

```
    package es.esy.buddy.com.simplechat;


    import android.app.ListFragment;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;


    /**
     * Created by Tuneer on 07-03-2017.
     */

    public class ListOfOnlineMember extends ListFragment {

        String[] countries = new String[] {
                "India",
                "Pakistan",
                "Sri Lanka",
                "China",
                "Bangladesh",
                "Nepal",
                "Afghanistan",
                "North Korea",
                "South Korea",

        };

        // Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable/
        int[] flags = new int[]{
                R.drawable.picture1,
                R.drawable.picture2,
                R.drawable.picture3,
                R.drawable.wallpaper2,
                R.drawable.wallpaper3,
                R.drawable.wallpaper5,
                R.drawable.wallpaper4,
                R.drawable.wallpaper6,
                R.drawable.wallpaper7,
        };

        // Array of strings to store currencies
        String[] currency = new String[]{
                "Indian Rupee",
                "Pakistani Rupee",
                "Sri Lankan Rupee",
                "Renminbi",
                "Bangladeshi Taka",
                "Nepalese Rupee",
                "Afghani",
                "North Korean Won",
                "South Korean Won",
        };

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
            List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
                hm.put("txt", countries[i]);
                hm.put("cur", currency[i]);
                hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );
                aList.add(hm);
            }

            // Keys used in Hashmap
            String[] from = { "flag","txt","cur" };

            // Ids of views in listview_layout
            int[] to = { R.id.imageviewshow,R.id.txtName,R.id.txtNumber};

            // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
            // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listviewonlinitems, from, to);

            setListAdapter(adapter);

            return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        }
    }

    #this is Java code for MainActivity.java what i write here is simple code just calling layout to show up but the app is not opening or its suddenly stopped whenever my code goes on this activity. 
    package es.esy.buddy.com.simplechat;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

    /**
     * Created by Tuneer on 07-03-2017.
     */

    public class OnlineChatMember extends FragmentActivity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(SavedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.onlinechatmember);
        }
    }

    #Errors i am getting Errors while opening the app on this activity showing this error but i used carefull with array then why it is showing array errors.

    03-09 04:21:27.399 6846-6846/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                     Process: es.esy.buddy.com.simplechat, PID: 6846
                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{es.esy.buddy.com.simplechat/es.esy.buddy.com.simplechat.OnlineChatMember}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class fragment
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class fragment
                                                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30: Error inflating class fragment
                                                      Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=9
                                                         at es.esy.buddy.com.simplechat.ListOfOnlineMember.onCreateView(ListOfOnlineMember.java:69)
                                                         at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2353)
                                                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:959)
                                                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1149)
                                                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1251)
                                                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2311)
                                                         at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98)
                                                         at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5884)
                                                         at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:36)
                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:77)
                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:777)
                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:414)
                                                         at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2414)
                                                         at es.esy.buddy.com.simplechat.OnlineChatMember.onCreate(OnlineChatMember.java:17)
                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

This is it so can u help me
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace states `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=9; index=9`

You are calling this code

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
    hm.put("txt", countries[i]);
    hm.put("cur", currency[i]);
    hm.put("flag", Integer.toString(flags[i]) );
    aList.add(hm);
}
```

Your various arrays (countries, currency, flags) have 9 elements, yet you clearly loop 10 times, hence you are getting the exception. I would suggesting replace `10` with `countries.length`

This is super simple java and really has nothing to do with the question asked. Simply readying the stack trace would have pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: it worked it worked thnks i am idiot i used a code to finish all the activity when there is no empty value for countries...that's why app or activity started shutting down every time i open it....thnks Joe Maher you saved me